# mysql - alter table modify column cannot delete rows

Tags: mysql, mariadb

So I'm trying to run this command:

```
ALTER TABLE user MODIFY COLUMN email VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE;
```

but it gives me this error,

```
Cannot delete rows from table which is parent in a foreign key constraint 'draft_map_ibfk_1' of table 'draft_map'
```

There are no duplicates in the table, so it shouldn't be deleting anything. The email column is currently a `TEXT`, so is that what's causing the issue?

Comment: You have a foreign key that relies on this row.

Comment: @jhpratt yes i know that, but I'm not deleting anything, does `ALTER TABLE` delete stuff and recreate it or something?

Comment: Whoops, misread the original query. `ALTER TABLE` recreates each row individually, so in a sense, yes, it deletes it (albeit temporarily).

Comment: @jhpratt ah I see, is there anyway to work around this? Just curious in case I ever need to modify a live database. Or will I need to take it offline and modify it?

Comment: I'm not aware of any workaround. I would personally just create a copy of it and work on that (by removing the foreign key). Then you can switch reliance on DBs when appropriate.

Comment: Voted this back up to 0 as it does show research and is clear, the fact that A. Lau knows this would occur to the UNIQUE constraint shows an understanding of the problem and it helps with answering this. I would ask what the email column was previous to the ALTER?

Comment: @Jools I believe it's as jhpratt said, it's because `ALTER TABLE` recreates the rows, which causes a temporary deletion

Comment: @A.Lau my understanding of the ALTER TABLE and all alterations in MYSQL is that of replication not deletion. A copy table is created with the ALTER changes and data is then copied across and the old table is deleted. Not a row by row deletion. I found this searching for an answer to the same problem, and our issue was due to the referenced data. I ask what you were ALTERing from as it may indicate the issue. I would suggest the 'draft_map_ibfk_1' fk is affecting a subsequent deletion(maybe in another table) as a result of the ALTER change?

Comment: @Jools that might be the case, though I'm not currently working on the project :\

Answer (score 1):

Temporary disable foreign hey checks:

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 0;
```

To enable it back use:

```
SET foreign_key_checks = 1;
```

Comment: And then the integrity will be destroyed?

Comment: @RickJames If I were to lock the database/(take it offline) and apply the changes, it should be fine, right?